# Detecting a Fasting State in the Body via Lasers

Tags: hematology

I was just wondering wether it would be possible to detect if the body is in a "fasting" state, via lasers attached to the body. If it is possible, what sort of laser would be needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by a fasting state, you mean blood glucose levels, researchers seem to think it is feasible. See for example Pleitez et al. ([1](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/rsi/84/8/10.1063/1.4816723)) and Guo et al. ([2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3493219/)). Their designs both utilize infrared IR laser light to measure glucose levels in the skin.